# Skip Blank Cells when using ArrayFormula in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm using a FormulaArray to convert fetched times from my Google Calendar to a 24 hour clock as opposed a 12 hour. I'm using a French Google account so it does not recognize AM and PM.

In column H I am using :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D;"[0-9]*\:[0-9]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+")))
```

to pick apart the date and avoid it blank spaces, but I can't seem to get the same formula to work in column I, where I am using :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR((TEXT(H3:H; "HH:MM:SS"))))
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to combine

=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(H3:H; "HH:MM:SS")) and =IF(I3="00:00:00";"";I3)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(H3:H;"HH:MM:SS"))="00:00:00";"";ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(H3:H;"HH:MM:SS"))))
```